# Java7 Type inference for generic instance creation?

Tags: java, java-7

How we can use Java 7 **Type inference for generic instance creation** feature ? What all benefits to use this new style?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is also known as the diamond operator.  It saves you from having to write the generic type arguments on the instantiation of a generic type.  The type arguments of the instantiated generic type are inferred from the type arguments present on the declaration.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Instead of:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: OK we do not need to write see both side of eqal operator

Comment: Exactly only the left side of the statement must specify the type arguments `<type>`, while the right side will be inferred from the left side.

Answer (score 2):

No. The diamond syntax is merely a shorthand in coding/typing. These two are the same

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();  
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

They are treated the same for the compiling process, hints to the compiler. Even before type erasure, they are treated the same. It's literally just a convenience for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's just less typing.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

> For example, consider the following variable declaration:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

> In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Unfortunately, [you still have to type the diamond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909875/why-diamond-operator-is-used-for-type-inference-in-java-7?rq=1).

Comment: Yes. That's all there is to it. You don't have to repeat the types twice in the same statement.