# Why undefined generic parameter of variable drops explicit generic parameter of it's method's return type?

Tags: java, generics

```java
public abstract class A<T> {
    public static void test(A i) { for (String s : i.get()) {} }
    public abstract Iterable<String> get();
}
```

Why for the code above I get:

```
incompatible types
required: String
found:    Object
```

But if I will change argument of `test` method to `A<Object>`, it will compile OK? Why undefined generic parameter of variable drops explicit generic parameter of it's method's return type?

Comment: `public void test(A<T> i) { for (String s : i.get()) {} }`

Comment: @TheNewIdiot It's a static method.

Comment: Ok , then it would be `public static void test(A<?> i) { for (String s : i.get()) {} }`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882003/generic-screws-up-non-related-collection/14882590#14882590

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why undefined generic parameter of variable drops explicit generic parameter of it's method's return type?

`A` is a *raw* type. That's a type with *all* generics dropped in the API dropped, even ones with fixed type arguments.

See the [JLS section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) and the [Raw Types section of the Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Raw%20Types) for more information.

In this case, if you want *any* `A`, you can use a wildcard:

```
public static void test(A<?> i)
```

Comment: Hello sir, May I get your help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155554/what-are-difference-of-int-initalize-values I read your post here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/662786-int-n-default-system-int32 can you please give us some more details ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: Please don't ask for help via comments on completely unrelated questions. Besides, you've already got plenty of answers - the three are entirely equivalent.