# what are difference of int initialize values?

Tags: c#

I had some confusions about [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147553/int-num-new-int-what-happens-when-this-line-executes).

What are differences between these terms?  When should I use what?

```
int x = default(int);
int x = 0;
int x = new int();
```

I read here in **[this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/662786-int-n-default-system-int32)**.

Comment: As stated in the link, they are identical. Choose whatever you prefer.

Comment: Are you really going to use `default(int)` or `new int()` in your code?

Comment: You should basically never use either 1 or 3, and use 2 only when declaring a local variable that might otherwise have definite assignment issues. `default()` should really be reserved for use with generics.

Comment: Choose none of them. Just use int x;

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same and as far as I can tell, they all result in the same IL:

```
ldc.i4.0
```

`default` is a handy keyword for generics. You can initialize a variable to its default value even without knowing its type. It would then be a null for reference types, 0 for int and respective default values for other structs.

The constructor, `new int()` is there because `int` is just a (value) type like any other, so it has a constructor and you can call it.

Semantically `new int()` and `0` are the same, the `default` is a little bit different thing, but in case of integers it results in the same code.

**Code example** (I think the only thing that deserves an example is the `default` keyword):

Suppose you have a simple implementation of **[`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx)** method (the code has been taken from **[edulinq](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/DefaultIfEmpty.cs)** and slightly modified - it's a great repository if you're interested in LINQ!). This method either yields the items of the source collection, or just one item, that is the default value of the specified generic type:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    bool foundAny = false;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        foundAny = true;
    }
    if (!foundAny)
    {
        yield return // What to return here?
    }
}
```

You want this to work on all types, but how do you get an instance of any type?
You don't know if it's and `int`, so that you could write `yield return 0` - that would not work when `TSource` is `string`. If you `yield return null`, that won't work for `int`...
Also some types might not have a parameterless constructor, some might not have an accessible constructor at all (a wierd case, but can happen, for example a collection containing some singleton instances) or maybe you have a collection of interface/abstract class type and you can't construct their instances (if you don't know another type implementing/inheriting them).

`default` is there exactly for these cases. You don't know what type `TSource` may be, but `default (TSource)` will give you the default value anyway.

If you call

```
var collectionWithZero = new int[0].DefaultIfEmpty<int>();
```

you will get a collection with one item, a zero. The method got compiled with an `int` as the `TSource`, so it calls `default (int)` and that results in 0. If you call the same method on an empty collection of strings, the method will be compiled for string as well and will use `default (string)`, which results in null (because that is the default value for all reference types).

As for the other two (`new int()` and `0`), I've already mentioned they mean the same, so just use the shorter one, zero. It's easier to read and to maintain, everyone knows what a zero is, so the constructor might only be confusing.

Comment: `new int(0)` doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh, you're right. For some reason I thought there's a constructor overload taking a value... Removing from the answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you show code example also for more clarity? Thank You for your precious time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**Always use**

```
int x = 0;
```

**or even just**

```
int x;
```

It's more maintainable, better readable than the other versions. Also it's much likely that less questions of your peer programmers will occur.

Answer (score 0):

They are all Same , just that framework offers different way to declare a variable . You can chose which ever you feel easy to use.