# Generic type of superclass property lost in subclass with no type bound

Tags: java, generics

Here is a pathological generics example in Java.  What is going on here?

```
public abstract class Foo<X> {

    private List<String> stuff;

    public List<String> getStuff() {
        return stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff(List<String> stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

Then I created a subclass, but not I did not specify the type bound, which should make it object.

```
public class Bar extends Foo {

    public Bar() {
        setStuff(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public void whatIsGoingOnHere() {

        for(String thing : getStuff())
            System.out.println("Why is this a compiler error???");
    }
}
```

Why is this a compiler error?

Comment: `public class Bar extends Foo<?>` fixes the issue?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001550

Comment: Raw types erase all generics, not just those related to the omitted type variables. You need `extends Foo<Object>`.

Answer (score -2):

You call `setStuff(new ArrayList<>());`. Here ArrayList<> isn't not bound, it is inferred by the compiler if it can. And it can as `setStuff` is `setStuff(List<String>)`. So the compiler knows it is a `ArrayList<String>` and uses (infers) that.

Your loop iterates over an `List<String>` as returned by the `getStuff()` method, so defining the `thing` as a `String` (or any super class or interface) will be okay for the compiler.

The base class does have an `X` type, but it doesn't matter as your stuff list is declared with a type. Only if you would define stuff as an `List<X>` it would matter what the subclass defined for `X`.